# Restrict dynamic content css attributes

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension that adds html elements into the users page content when the page loads. The styles of the elements that the extension inserts are specified in the extension's css. This mostly works fine.

The problem: Sometimes I will have styling issues with the elements for my extension because the site that the user visits has a style sheet which has styles such as `*{ ... }` or `img{ ... }`, and the styles are applied to my extension's elements.

I want to find a way to ensure that the html elements that my chrome extension inserts into a website's page content are only affected by my css, and are not affected by the css of the sites that a user visits. One way that I've accomplished this is my giving most of my html elements types such as `<myExtensionDiv>` instead of `<div>`. However, this doesn't work in cases where the website uses `*{ ... }` and I can't avoid using `<img>` elements in my extension's html, so they are often affected.

Comment: I don't think you can go up against the CSS of every possible web page out there.  You're most likely better off namespacing your elements and using a lot of !important in your CSS.

Comment: The content of the question has nothing to with CSS inheritance (the most widely misunderstood CSS concept). It is vague and seems to aim at something that uses CSS but works against basic principles of CSS, like the cascade.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Sorry for using the word inheritance. Fixed. How is my question vague? I give examples, and explain what I've tried.

Comment: @NaNpx Unfortunately using !important just stops an attribute from being overridden. If there is an attribute in the source css, that I haven't specified in my own css then there is no way to stop it from being applied to my html elements.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Also, I don't have control over the source page css. My extension is dynamically inserting html elements, and dynamically adding css to the source css. There is no way for me to strictly follow css principles in this case, which is why I'm here.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5145620/1507998