# Prevent injected HTML from taking website's CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I'm making a simple extension for FF and Chrome that will *inject* a `<div>` on the top of the page (right after `<body>`). The problem is that some websites have global CSS rules for buttons or borders, etc. Eg:

```
button, input[type="button"], input[type="submit"] { 
    color:#050; 
    font: bold 84% 'trebuchet ms',helvetica,sans-serif; 
    background-color:#fed; 
    border:1px solid; 
    border-color: #696 #363 #363 #696; 
}
```

I want the buttons (and other elements) inside my injected div to use only the CSS from their classes and nothing else. Is it possible to make those elements *reject* "foreign" CSS ?

Thank you.

Comment: A temporary fix would be to write inline CSS it will override the CSS on the webpage. I will look for better answers and get back to you.

Comment: @kiran.koduru <button style="color:#050;">X</button> It will still get the font, background-color and border from the CSS

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn Good idea! Didn't think of that option.

Comment: insert an iframe and then load your widget inside the iframe. its much easier to handle setting iframes css to none then a bunch of elements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Isolating CSS for Chrome extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145620/isolating-css-for-chrome-extension)

Comment: To comment on the above duplicate: it has more detailed answers, and mentions the most modern approach ([Shadow DOM](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting it in an iframe fixed it

Answer (score -1):

Since you're injecting code into the DOM, that HTML is subject any CSS that applies to it.

I would recommend simply overriding the CSS for your injected DIV by using a unique ID.

HTML:

```
<div id="uniqueIdThatNobodyWouldUse">
    <input type="text" name="input" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#uniqueIdThatNobodyWouldUse input {
    color:#000; 
    font: bold 84% 'trebuchet ms',helvetica,sans-serif; 
    background-color:#fed; 
    border:1px solid; 
    border-color: #696 #363 #363 #696; 

}
```

And if you really want to be sure, you can apply `!important` to force and imposing CSS.

```
#uniqueIdThatNobodyWouldUse input {
    color:#000 !important;
    font: bold 84% 'trebuchet ms',helvetica,sans-serif !important; 
    background-color:#fed !important; 
    border:1px solid !important;
    border-color: #696 #363 #363 #696 !important; 

}
```

Comment: but my input would still use other CSS rules that are not mentioned in my uniqueID css, right? eg.: padding, width, etc

Comment: Yes, which is why you should override absolutely everything you need to ensure it looks correctly.  There is no reject foreign CSS option.